# Selenium selector to select input in second td by text in the first

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Looking for a selenium selector that I can use the text in the first td to selected the input in the second.

```
<tr><th>asdf</th><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><th>qwer</th><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><th>rtyu</th><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><th>fghj</th><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a document:

```
<html>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>qwer</td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>rtyu</td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>fghj</td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
</html>
```

Use this as a xpath expression:

```
//tr/td[text()="asdf"]//following-sibling::td
```

Here is a nice page where you can test it online and play around till you've got the correct syntax:
http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx

Take look at the [following-sibling](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example15.html) xpath example and the [Selenium locator reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html).

**Answer Updated!**